# Adding default value to text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textarea, default-value

I am using the following script to add default values to input text boxes:

```
$('.default-value').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).css('color', '#746F66'); // this could be in the style sheet instead
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            $(this).css('color', '#746F66');
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
```

With the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
    <input type="textbox" class="default-value" name="Name" id="Name" value="Full Name">

    <input type="textbox" class="default-value" name="Email" id="Email" value="Email">

    <textarea name="Message" class="default-value" name="Message" id="Message" value="Your message"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
```

The default values work fine for the textboxes, but I can't work out how to get the default value into the textarea.  At the moment nothing is showing up in the textarea, as you can see [here](http://www.bodhitreebrighton.org.uk/test/contact.html).

Could someone help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
var default_value = this.value;
```

To:

```
var default_value = $(this).val();
```

This is because a `textarea` doesn't have a `value` attribute, to assign a default text to this element simple place the text between the opening, and closing, tags of the element, as such:

```
<textarea name="Message" class="default-value" name="Message" id="Message">Your message.</textarea>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4TtfH/).

---

**Edited** after testing, in Chromium 12/Ubuntu 11.04, to discover that as far as JavaScript is concerned (at least for this browser/platform) `var default_value = this.value;` works to assign the `default_value` correctly.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4TtfH/1/).

Comment: textarea's also have a value-attribute.